# Tablefilter: How to set "default value" in select-Filter?

Tags: tablefilter

I have a column with values "active" and "inactive" and configured that column per "col_n" as 'select".

So the Filter shows "Clear", "active" and "inactive".

I want pre-select that filter on "active".

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
      on_filters_loaded: function(tf){
        tf.setFilterValue(n, 'aktiv');
        tf.filter();
      },
```

"n" is number of column (starting with 0)